# `ds.` prefix on Hive tables when accessed via JDBC

Tags: postgresql, hadoop, jdbc, hive

I have a HiveServer2 running with JDBC connections and it works fine from Impala, Beeline and Spark clients. The metastore is running in a PostgreSQL server.

For example, the columns in Hive are

```
select * from testdb.test_table limit 3;

dt | val_test | val_test_b | test_c
12    0.2        B             C
13    1.2        B             A
14    9.4        T             C
```

When I try to access the same tables from ZoomData, all column tables get a `ds.` prefix that is not in the original table column names:

```
ds.dt   | ds.val_test  | ds.val_test_b | ds.test_c
12             0.2        B             C
13             1.2        B             A
14             9.4        T             C
```

and sometimes, when accessing the data, the Zoomdata JDBC client gives

```
Error: cannot find `ds.val_test` column. 
Error: cannot find `ds_val_test` column.
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: its probably just aliases - does it affect result?..

Comment: It does. Sometime it's not possible to even access the columns. Where is this alias being created?

Comment: show uz queries please or at least some code or data

Comment: Zoomdata creates an outer SQL to the given SQL and maybe it has added ds as alias to the table. Have you given custom SQL or selected normal table?